# Error due to Ammeter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

With relation to the attached question/picture.

I think the 2.372A is correct, and if I remove the ammeter, and caclulate I, I then get 2.4A.

I then caclulate the percentage as:

2.4A / 100 = 0.024A to give me 1%.

I then did (0.024 / 2.372) x 100% = 1.01%

But I've gone wrong somewhere? Any pointers please so I can try and work it out?

Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: This is not a homework site. Questions asking "What did I do wrong?" do not fit well with the aim of the site, which is to explain conceptual difficulties. See the [homework-and-exercises policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't realise that. I'm doing a home learning course, but appreciate you cannot ask questions like this.

Comment: A fledgling offshoot site called [Physics Problems Q&A](http://physicsproblems.nfshost.com//?qa=questions) has been created to handle such questions which are tagged here as "Homework and Exercises". Some effort is still expected but the aim is to be much more relaxed about the kind of questions which are welcomed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link.

I did try to solve my question though :)

Comment: Yes, you did. But the question is not asking about a conceptual difficulty. The rationale is that the question should be useful to other users. Identifying your mistake is useful to you, but not to other users.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the error is the difference between the two measurements, which is 0.028A.
Dividing 2.4 by 100 is irrelevant.